# Swift 3: Property observer for singleton

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I wonder if there's any way to observe singleton class for changes in ony of its property

In my case, with Realm I have something like this

```
class User: Object {
   dynamic var name:String = ""
   dynamic var email:String = ""
   dynamic var id:String = ""
   dynamic var picURL:String = ""
   dynamic var pic:Data = Data()

    static let currentUser = User()
    {
        didSet
        {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(currentUser, update: true)
            }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is I want to have only one user object in my app, and anytime any of its properties gets modified, I would like to save it to Realm.

However, the example above shows error that

> 'let' declarations cannot be observing properties

How would you approach it? Do you think my idea with having Realm object singleton and updating it anytime some property changes is a good idea?

I wonder if it actually makes any sense to have a singleton object of class that is persisted by Realm.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve:
Either one can modify `currentUser`, then this should be a `var`, not a `let`
Or one cannot modify `currentUser` (as by now, since it's a `let` constant), but in this case, you won't need a listener upon setting it.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Could you specify what part of my explanation is unclear?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Note that if I modify it into var, it would no longer be singleton

Comment: If you want to have a singleton, you should implement a getter for currentUser, and create a private initializer private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It's not possible to have a blanket observer for a single Realm `Object` at the moment, however there's [an issue tracking it in the Realm GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3431) and I *believe* it's being prioritized at the moment.</s>

Alcivanio is correct in that you'll need to manually trigger an update event to ensure the changes are persisted to Realm. That being said, because Realm controls the accessors in persisted objects, `didSet` isn't guaranteed to be called once an object has been saved to Realm. For simplicity reasons, I'd recommend using a closure to update the user object.

***Updated Answer:*** If your singleton is a Realm `Object`, you can't modify its properties outside of a write transaction. Like I wrote below, the easiest thing to do would be to be to have an `update` closure that managed the Realm write transaction, and you simply update the properties of your Singleton object inside it.

As you've also seen, you can't use `didSet` with a property defined with `let`, so it might be best to drop back to Objective-C conventions and use an internal instance variable.

So all up, maybe consider doing this:

```
fileprivate var _current: User? = nil

class User: Object {
    dynamic var name:String = ""
    dynamic var email:String = ""
    dynamic var id:String = ""
    dynamic var picURL:String = ""
    dynamic var pic:Data = Data()

    static var current: User
    {
        if _current == nil {
            let realm = try! Realm()

            // Query for an existing user
            _current = realm.objects(User.self).first

            // Create a new user if it didn't exist in Realm
            if _current == nil {
                 _current = User()
                 try! realm.write { realm.add(_current) }
            }
        }
        return _current
    }

    public func update(_ block: (() -> Void)) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write(block)
    }
}

let user = User.current
user.update {
    user.name = "DCDC"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm getting `instance member '_current' be used on type 'User'`

Comment: @DCDC That's weird. Alright. I updated the answer. I did some research into Swift singletons and confirmed this method works (Put `_current` out of the scope of the class).

Comment: I probably should point out this version will create a new `User` and save it to Realm every time the app is run. If you only ever want one `User` object representing this user, it might be more appropriate to run a query and only create a new `User` object if the Realm file doesn't already have one.

Comment: I got some other issues with this approach - when I logout I delete the user from realm, so now when I try to login user does not exist any longer. It would be best when update method would work in the following way - if there is no user, create one, or update already existing one

Comment: Hmm okay. If you delete the object in Realm, `_current` won't automatically become `nil`. You'll need to make sure that upon logging out, `_current` is set to `nil` as well.

Comment: I updated the sample to perform a basic query to see if the object already exists in Realm beforehand.

Comment: I cannot modify current from my logout function since it's fileprivate. Nonetheless, I accept this answer since it answer my question about updating objects, now it's up to me I guess how to deal with logging out and keep track that only one user in Realm exists

Comment: Haha thanks! Alright. Good luck! If you need anymore Realm-related help with that, feel free to create a new question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134354/discussion-between-dcdc-and-tim).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just have one user, you should put this observer in each variable, instead of in the *let user*. And there you can call a method for user update.

```
dynamic var name: String {
    didSet{
        User.updateOnRealm()//create this method
    }
}
```

To write the update method, you'll have to write something like this

```
class func updateOnRealm() {
    //update code here
}
```

Comment: ok, so this is the only way to do that, I cannot observe for all changes in currentUser object?

Comment: Do you want to observe if the `currentUser` is modified, or if the properties any of the User is modified?

Comment: @DCDC It seems that no, you can't observe the let user. You'll not be able to change the user, but you'll be able to change it's variables. So, it doesn't make sense to me to observe the user using the didSet. Maybe there is another way to do it. Share with us if you find it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote :

> What I want to achieve is I want to have only one user object in my app, and anytime any of its properties gets modified, I would like to save it to Realm.

I would suggest this solution:

1. Create a `class User` which does not use the Singleton pattern.
2. Create a `class UserManager` which does conform to the Singleton pattern
3. Create custom setter methods for `A` User. In these setters you can then change the users properties WITH or WITHOUT writing to the database. You can also check the use INPUT (set the name to lowercase etc.).

With this approach you can easily test your `User` class, extend it, subclass and reuse.

If you need code snippets comment below =).