# Swift 3: Realm creates additional object instead of updating the exisiting one

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

In my AppDelegate

```
let realm = try! Realm()
    print("number of users")
    print(realm.objects(User.self).count)
    if !realm.objects(User.self).isEmpty{
        if realm.objects(User.self).first!.isLogged {
            User.current.setFromRealm(user: realm.objects(User.self).first!)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"TabBar") as! CustomTabBarController
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        }
    } else {
        try! realm.write { realm.add(User.current) }
    }
```

I create user only when there are no user objects across the app

thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929304/4286947) I update my object in the following way

```
public func update(_ block: (() -> Void)) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write(block)
}
```

But it turns out it creates new User object. How to always update the already existing one instead of creating new object?

Note that I use `User.current` since my object is a singleton

After I login and logout, it prints number of users = 2, which means that updating already existing user creates a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realm.write` is incapable of adding new objects, unless you're calling `realm.add` inside of it. If you're getting 2 objects in the database, it either means that your logic for checking if the object already exists is failing, or the logic for deleting the previous object when logging out is failing.

Calling `realm.add` on the same object twice will not add 2 copies to the database, so it could also indicate you're creating 2 unmanaged `User` objects in your logic as well.

In any case, I'd recommend double-checking your logic to absolutely ensure you're not adding two objects to Realm by accident.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let firstUser = realm.objects(User.self).first

if let firstUser = firstUser {
    User.current.setFromRealm(user: firstUser)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"TabBar") as! CustomTabBarController
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
}
else {
    try! realm.write { realm.add(User.current) }
}
```

Comment: I did add object elsewhere in my former db-related class manager, I managed to fix it by myself, still I think this answer deserves acceptance :)

Answer (score 7):

Realm will check if the object exist or not for you. Only use `add` and `update`.

```
// Create or update the object
try? realm.write {
   realm.add(self, update: true)
}
```

Documentation :

```
 - parameter object: The object to be added to this Realm.
 - parameter update: If `true`, the Realm will try to find an existing copy of the object (with the same primary
                     key), and update it. Otherwise, the object will be added.
```