# Realm is creating multiple entries for nested objects on update

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I'm experiencing trouble understanding how updating objects works in Realm. I'd appreciate help in helping me to understand how updating **nested objects** work and why it doesn't work the way I expect it.

I started using Realm just recently, and here's what I want to use it for: I have a set of key value pairs stored on my server, that serve as localized values for strings used in my iOS app. On app launch every now and then I want to update my strings, so I pull them from the server and store them locally in realm on my iOS device. I want to have only **ONE instance** of those strings on my device.

Here are the classes:

```
import RealmSwift

public class LocalizedStrings: Object {
   dynamic var id = 1
   dynamic var version: String = ""
   let assets = List<LocalizedString>()
   override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "id"
   }
}

public class LocalizedString: Object {
    dynamic var key: String = ""
    dynamic var value: String = ""
}
```

Here's how I update the LocalizedStrings object:

```
realm.add(localizedStrings, update: true)
```

Here's how I access my strings:

```
func getLocalizedString(forKey key: String) -> String {
    var result = key
    try! realm.write {
        let queryResult = realm.objects(LocalizedString.self).filter("key == %@", key)
        // print(queryResult)
        if queryResult.count == 1 {
            result = queryResult[0].value(forKey: "value") as! String
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Now, I would expect, that whenever I update my LocalizedStrings, that the `localizedStrings.assets` list would get updated with new values. But instead, the assets are not updated, the **list reference gets updated** and I end up having multiple instances of the same string, which is not what I would expect from an update function. When I try to access a particular LocalizedString, it turns out there's multiple instances:

```
(...)
[19] LocalizedString {
    key = update;
    value = Update;
},
[20] LocalizedString {
    key = update;
    value = Update;
}
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious and I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, so I'd be able to achieve the behavior I'm looking for (which would be having the nested object actually updated, rather than having unnecessary duplicates of my objects).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you also updating the individual `LocalizedString` objects, or are they getting added anew? It seems like the latter is happening, somehow. How are the `LocalizedStrings` and `LocalizedString` objects created and built before writing to Realm? Perhaps giving `LocalizedString` a primary key and doing an update on those objects would help? I'm not positive though :P

Comment: @Samantha, yup! Adding the primary key for `LocalizedString` solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41934400/4811994) helped me figure out, what was wrong with my setup. I was missing primaryKey in LocalizedString class.

From the answer above on how `realm.add(object, update: true)` works:

> Documentation :
>
> - parameter object: The object to be added to this Realm.
> - parameter update: If `true`, the Realm will try to find an existing copy of the object (**with the same primary
>                      key**), and update it. Otherwise, the object will be added.

So the same thing happens with **nested objects**. They can not be updated unless they have primaryKey.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have `Media` object which have nested `Comment` object. If I don't implement `primaryKey` for `Comment` - it usually duplicates all `Comment` objects, if I implement `primaryKey` for `Comment` - it throws `Can't create object with existing primary key value '.....'`   `primaryKey` for `Media` implemented and I add `Media` in Realm like this `BaseStorage.add(media, update: true)`